# How to display output of one function after another

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, sorting, output

I have written a Javascript file of two algorithms. As shown in the code below, I am using a `for loop` to generate random values which are used by both algorithms as input.

At present, I am displaying output of the `binarySearch` and `SearchSorted` alternatively.

The problem I am facing is I have to pass the ***same array values*** generated by `randomlyGenerateArray` in the ***main program*** to both the algorithms for a meaningful comparison. But I don't know how to change the output format.

I have thought of adding them in different loops, but as I have explained above i need to use the same `randomArray` values for both the algorithms.

i.e., The below code produces output as shown below -

`Binary Search Successful 1
 Search Sorted Successful 5
 Binary Search Successful 3
 Search Sorted Successful 10`

How do I display the output of Binary Search First and then display output of Search Sorted? it's something like this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

`Binary Search Successful 1
 Binary Search Successful 3
 Search Sorted Successful 5
 Search Sorted Successful 10`

```
// Binary Search Algorithm
function binarySearch(A,K)
{
     var l = 0; // min
     var r = A.length - 1; //max
     var n = A.length;
     var operations = 0;

     while(l <= r)
     {   
          var m = Math.floor((l + r)/2);
          operations++;

          if(K == A[m])
          {
              console.log('Binary Search Successful %d',operations);
              return m;
          }
          else if(K < A[m])
          {
              r = m - 1;
          }
          else
          {
              l = m + 1;
          }
     }
     operations++;
     console.log('Binary Search Unsuccessful %d',operations);
     return -1;
}

// Search Sorted Algorithm
function searchSorted(A, K) 
{
    var n = A.length;
    var i = 0;
    var operations = 0;

    while (i < n) 
    {
        operations++;
        if (K < A[i]) 
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (K == A[i])
        {
            console.log('Search Sorted Successful %d', operations);
            return i;
        }
        else 
        {
            i = i + 1;
        }
   }
   operations++;
   console.log('Search Sorted Unsuccessful %d', operations);
   return -1;
}

// Random Array generator
var randomlyGenerateArray = function(size)
{
    var array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        var temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxArrayValue);
        var final = array.splice(5, 0, 30);
        array.push(final);
    }
    return array;
}

//Sort the Array
var sortNumber = function(a, b)
{
    return a - b;
}

// Main Program
var program = function()
{
    var incrementSize = largestArray / numberOfArrays;
    for (var i = smallestArray; i <= largestArray; i += incrementSize)
    {
        var randomArray = randomlyGenerateArray(i);
        var sort = randomArray.sort(sortNumber);
        var randomKey = 30;
        binarySearch(sort, randomKey);
        searchSorted(sort, randomKey);
    }
}

var smallestArray = 10;
var largestArray = 10000;
var numberOfArrays = 1000;
var minArrayValue = 1;
var maxArrayValue = 1000;

program();
```

Comment: Separate the binary and sorted search into 2 loops. Also, just ti clarify, Are you supposed to generate a new array on each step?

Comment: I need to use the same `randomArray` as input to both the algorithms. If I separate them then I will have to call `randomlyGenerateArray` again for the other loop, which then will not have the same array values as that of the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the sorted `randomArray`s in an array (which I've called `sortedRandomArrays`), then run a for loop for each search.

The Main Program would then look like:

```
// Main Program
var program = function()
{
    var incrementSize = largestArray / numberOfArrays;
    var sortedRandomArrays = [];
    for (var i = smallestArray; i <= largestArray; i += incrementSize)
    {
        var randomArray = randomlyGenerateArray(i));
        var sort = randomArray.sort(sortNumber);
        sortedRandomArrays.push(sort);
        var randomKey = 30;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < sortedRandomArrays.length; i++)
    {
        binarySearch(sortedRandomArrays[i], randomKey);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < sortedRandomArrays.length; i++)
    {
        searchSorted(sortedRandomArrays[i], randomKey);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution is simple: store the results and print with 2 separate loops (take out the printing from within the functions).

```
var program = function()
{
    var binarySearchResults = [];
    var sortedSearchResults = [];
    var incrementSize = largestArray / numberOfArrays;
    for (var i = smallestArray; i <= largestArray; i += incrementSize)
    {
        var randomArray = randomlyGenerateArray(i);
        var sort = randomArray.sort(sortNumber);
        var randomKey = 30;
        binarySearchResults[i] = binarySearch(sort, randomKey);
        sortedSearchResults[i] = searchSorted(sort, randomKey);
    }

    for (var i = smallestArray; i <= largestArray; i += incrementSize)
    {
       //print binary results
    }

    for (var i = smallestArray; i <= largestArray; i += incrementSize)
    {
       //print sorted results
    }

}
```

Comment: the way I have written the above code is to reuse the `randomArray` code for both the algorithms if I take it out of the loop it will not create an array of different lengths. I need to create array of different length until the for loop condition is met and then reuse the same array.

Comment: In your above 1st answer, the `randomlyGenerateArray(i)` if taken outside the loop won't create an array of different lengths. It will give me an Undefined error.

Comment: Oh, so you need a new array with each step?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do an empirical comparison between two algorithms. For that, I need to use the same data for a meaningful comparison.

Comment: Thank You for the answer and suggestions :)